# HardOps: Is there a modifier pin option?

Tags: modifiers, interface, hard-ops

I was wondering if there is a way to pin a modifier to stay last or first in the modifier stack; I use Hardops and it usually forces the bevel modifier to stay last even if you add booleans and such, but when introducing vertex groups it want do that anymore, so regardless if there is anything I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a certain type of modifier to float to the top, you can mess with HardOps's options.  From there you can choose which modifiers are sent to the bottom of the stack when added, otherwise they'll stay where they land.

[image]

From the same window you can also set an ignore flag (by default: a space before the modifier name), which will leave that modifier alone and not consider it as part of the HardOps sort modifier settings.

The following is a link to HOps's semi-official YouTube manual explaining how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfIqWv5LFvo

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it seems that it does not work, nothing changes when i toggle off the ' Ignore Bevels with VGroups ' in both Hops and Boxcutter, the booleans still are not sorted as intended, No clue why !